# MySQL Visual Studio Cannot create a design window for the selected object

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, database-design

Why when I want to open design view of table in MySQL database It every time throws error

[image: Visual Studio MySQL error opening design view]

I can view data, edit data, manage data but can't edit table definition. I use Visual Studio 2015 Community, MarriaDB 10.1.9 and MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6.

Comment: Sounds like Visual Studio is the wrong tool.  Have a look at MySQL Workbench and phpmyadmin.

Comment: I don't want to use these tools. I usually use MS SQL server and sometimes I have to work with MySQL. I want to have all databases on one place - in IDE what I use.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you had a chance to solve it?

Comment: No I haven't. I have tried answer from @TK-421 but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by uninstalling Connector 6.9.9 and installing 6.9.8 - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

Comment: It works. Visual Studio 2015 Community + DotNet Connector 6.9.8 + MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.3 is working combination.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about v2.0.5? It is the only version that works on VS2017 currently.

Comment: It works. Visual Studio 2017 Community + DotNet Connector 6.9.8 + MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Dot Net Connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: I installed it and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2018 now, just thought I'd throw one out there. After several hours of trying random variations I got it to work using other people's answers.

I actually got the development download and it works but only with:

- *MySQL for Visual Studios 2.0.5*
- *Connector/NET 6.9.8*
- *Visual Studio 2017*

## Compatibility Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html

## Connector Archive *(originally shared by [Christopher Hustman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750934/christopher-hustman))*:

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

Comment: @stigzler sounds like you forgot to do a clean install or something. I wouldn't have posted it if it didn't work for me. Sorry yours broke, that doesn't make it the wrong answer bud.

Comment: It wasn't my installation as I got it successfuly working via the good advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393375/visual-studio-failed-to-link-mysql-database-table-to-dataset/49444077#comment93922116_49444077