# Cannot create a design window for the selected object Visual Studio 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I double click on a table to open in a design view it never works and says "Cannot create a design window for the selected object". I am also using MySQL Workbench to actually populate the table but I am not able to design them in Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092741/mysql-visual-studio-cannot-create-a-design-window-for-the-selected-object