# MySQL Visual Studio 2015 Cannot create a design window for the selected object

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, database-design

Whenever I try to open my table in Visual Studio in it gives an error saying

> "Cannot create design window for the selected object"

I've searched around, but none of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092741/mysql-visual-studio-cannot-create-a-design-window-for-the-selected-object) work.

I went to the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) provided in the above answer, but it says

> "Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the
>   MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now
>   available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio
>   available using the MySQL Installer for Windows."

And I have used the MySQL Installer for windows itself.
I'm using Python 3.4 on Visual Studio 2015 and MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Connector 6.9.8 - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/ - do not use 6.9.9 it has a bug that still displays "Cannot create design window for the selected object"

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the supported versions of Connector/NET for specific versions of Visual Studio are documented on the [MySQL Visual Studio installation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html).  According to that, for VS 2015 you would need

> MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 or 2.0.2 with Connector/NET 6.9.8

For what it's worth, I had the same error with VS 2017; and was able to resolve it by installing Connector/NET 8.0.18 as per those instructions.