# Visual Studio - Failed to link MySql database table to DataSet

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, dataset

When I try to drag a MySQL table to a DataSet after successfully adding a connection to a database in Server Explorer, I receive two error messages, one after the other:

> "Some updating commands could not be generated automatically. The database returned the following error: Unexpected error."
>
> "Mouse drag operation failed. Could not retrieve schema information for table or view."

Based on answers for similiar problems, I reinstalled `'MySqlConnector/Net'` and `'MySql for Visual Studio'`, and the same problem persists. I would like to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. After hours and hours of tinkering I found out that the current versions of MySql-for-visual-studio and MySqlConnector/Net have a bug, which can only be fixed by unninstalling those and installing `MySQL-for-visual-studio-1.2.6.msi` and `MySqlConnector-6.9.8.msi`, exactly in this order.

Answer (score 3):

This worked, except I had to install 1.2.7 before I could get MYSQL to show up as an option as data provider.

Comment: I confirm that this solution worked for me too (1.2.7 inplace of the 1.2.6). Thank you.

Comment: Awesome sauce. Me three - 1.2.7 MforVS followed by 6.9.8 MC worked a charm in VS2017 15.8.5. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

in my case the error statement was "you have a usable connection already" rather than "Unexpected Error" when adding a table as a data source, the above solution with MySql for VS 1.2.7 and MySql .net connector 6.9.8 worked for me as well. these need to be installed in the exact order as mentioned above. I'm using VS2017 15.9.11.