# Visual Studio 2017 and MySQL - "Could not retrieve schema information for table or view"

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm having ongoing problems getting MySQL and VS2107 playing nicely together. I seem to hit a snag ever few months where previously working setups all of a sudden stop working. This brings my dev to a standstill as I can no longer access my MySql databases.

The most recent issue is when trying to update/add tables via "Data Sources>Configure Data Source with Wizard" and then adding a table. I am faced with this error:

[image: error]

Previous to this, I had a number of other problems. I've solved these historically but choosing different versions of "MySQL for Visual Studio" and "MySql Connect/NET." However, I can't seem to get any permutations of these working. What I've tried:

MySQLForVisualStudio-1.2.7, MySQLConnectorNet-6.9.8, MySQL.Data-8.0.16
(as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393375/visual-studio-failed-to-link-mysql-database-table-to-dataset))

MySQLForVisualStudio-2.0.5, MySQLConnectorNet-6.9.9, MySQL.Data-8.0.16
(as per [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVXcbhwLyF8))

MySQLForVisualStudio-2.0.5, MySQLConnectorNet-6.9.10, With additional reference adding (as per [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHkSAAmx9WI))

also tried swapping in MySql.Data 6.9.9 dll into references rather than most recent version. Also tried different versions of MySql.data from NuGet. Also altered machine.config to ensure right versions are held therein.

I've also tried 'stock' options of most recent versions of all three (mysql.data from NuGet + most up to date MySql connector and VS)

This is driving me nuts. Every time this happens my dev comes to an absolute standstill. I can't believe that two solid technologies like VS and MySql have so much difficulty getting along! Also, it seems like I go for a period where it works OK, but then it mysteriously fails.

The other thing is that I can retrieve data for all of the tables via the "Server Explorer." however, when I try to drag and drop a table onto the dataset/xsd designer, I get: "Mouse drag failed - Could not retrieve schema for table or view" again.

I'd be really appreciative of any advice as this is proving to be a real blow for my dev - short of totally re-doing 6 months of code to incorporate a different db tech - no idea what to do.

Comment: Wizards would have been the death of me but I don't use them. I write code. Remember that there is a little man behind the curtain controlling the "wizard"

Comment: Sadly, Mary, I'm in too deep now and rely on this VS functionality - besides, it works intermittently. Thus, there's little I can do with your advice, but thanks anyway.